# image on the left side of the UITableViewCell disappears

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am setting programmatically simple Table view. Everything is okay except for when I don't set image to cell's imageView and only set a backgroundColor option to `UIColor.black`. It just disappears, maybe someone knows what my problem is here?

```
    import UIKit

    class FriendRequestsController: UITableViewController {

    static let cellId = "cellId"
    static let headerId = "headerId"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        navigationItem.title = "Friend Requests"

        tableView.separatorColor = UIColor.rgb(229, green: 231, blue: 235)
        tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = 26

        tableView.register(FriendRequestCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: FriendRequestsController.cellId)
        tableView.register(RequestHeader.self, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: FriendRequestsController.headerId)
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 2
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell =  tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: FriendRequestsController.cellId)!

      //cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named:"gandhi_profile")

        cell.imageView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.black

      return cell
    }

       override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 60
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let header = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: FriendRequestsController.headerId) as! RequestHeader

        if section == 0 {
            header.nameLabel.text = "FRIEND REQUESTS"
        } else {
            header.nameLabel.text = "PEOPLE YOU MAY KNOW"
        }

        return header
    }

     }

    class RequestHeader: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {

    override init(reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        setupViews()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    let nameLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "FRIEND REQUESTS"
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10)
        label.textColor = UIColor(white: 0.4, alpha: 1)
        return label
    }()

    let bottomBorderView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.rgb(229, green: 231, blue: 235)
        return view
    }()

    func setupViews() {
        addSubview(nameLabel)
        addSubview(bottomBorderView)

        addConstraintsWithFormat("H:|-8-[v0]-8-|", views: nameLabel)
        addConstraintsWithFormat("V:|[v0][v1(0.5)]|", views: nameLabel, bottomBorderView)

        addConstraintsWithFormat("H:|[v0]|", views: bottomBorderView)
    }

     }

     class FriendRequestCell: UITableViewCell {

       override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
         super.init(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    //    setupViews()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    }

}
```

So in the point where am I adding backgroundColor and removing image it just disapears(

Comment: where is imageView outlet in your cell? or how you adding your imageView in cell?

Comment: What is the purpose of the background color of a imageView? Is it used when you are setting the opacity of an image?  The image will cover the background so it is not clear.

Comment: I just can't get why it appears when i set image, but disappears when just set backroundcolor. why? Isn't it that UIImageView can show itself without setting image but just setting gackgroundcolor? but here it do not do it, and i am try to get why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to me, you should get `FriendRequestCell` in `cellForRowAt indexPath` method.

Please find this,

I've create **ListTableCell** and **xib** for the Cell, Please find my **ListTableCell** here,

```
class ListTableCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var imgView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblTemp: UILabel!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
}
```

On ViewController,

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let nib = UINib(nibName: "ListTableCell", bundle: nil)
    tblList.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "ListTableCell")

    getItems()
}

func getItems() {
    for i in 0...20 {
        arrItems.append("Test \(i)")
    }
}


extension Tab2VC: UITableViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return arrItems.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ListTableCell", for: indexPath) as! ListTableCell
        //cell.imgView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "yelp")
        cell.imgView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        cell.lblTemp.text = arrItems[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 60
    }
}
```

It works fine for me, Please try with this.

Comment: my question was about default UITableViewCell.imageView property why if i don't set UIImage to it it just disappears.

Comment: @N.Khasanov please see this https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623270-imageview

Comment: If you set the image then it appears, otherwise it will not appear

Comment: >_< but why , just why they afraid to allow not to set image but just tincolor or backgroundcolor.... thank you but(((((

Comment: @N.Khasanov if you really want to do it, why don't you create custom cell?

Comment: i know how to do it and i had done it long ago(in a programmatic way with constraints a so on and it work so cool),but nonetheless i am just struggling to get to the root of the matter with this stupid question.